# Consume webservice in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am writing my first WP7 app, and the data I'm trying to access is from a WebService. If I add a Service Reference, the actual methods return DataTables, which are not supported in WP7. Is there a way around this, or should I resort to a simple WebClient request and parse the xml myself?

The xml result has a DataSet schema which is where the service reference is pulling the info from.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can serialise the dataset to xml using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer in the service end and also deserialize in the phone.

Comment: I have no control over the service, so using WCF style usage will not seem to work as it's a baked in soap/dataset schema. Just seeing if there are any other alternatives to my above.

Comment: Ohh ok, In that case If i was you I would use the OData WP7 client thats available, its a very simple protocol and should be easy to implement